# How to draw border aound image

Tags: java, android

I have a ImageView with image, how can I draw border around image. The main problem is that image not a rectangle or circle and not cover full View. For example I want make something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not so trivial. But I think if you use these steps, you should be able to pull this off:

1) Extract Bitmap from ImageView (or instead just take it directly from the resource you are using).

2) Iterate over all the pixels. If one of the neighbor pixels is not empty (transparent/white) and current pixel is empty then set pixel to red (do this only after you finished the iteration).

3) Set bitmap back to ImageView.